# iterating through XNA gametime delay timer in arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, xna

I am trying iterate through an array of Bullets in order to set the position of each one with a delay of 0.3 secs.

```
FireTimer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

            if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && FireTimer > FireRate)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Count(); i++)
                {
                    if (bullets[i].IsAlive == false)
                    {
                        bullets[i].IsAlive = true;
                        bullets[i].position = position;
                        FireTimer = 0f;
                    }
                }

            }
```

My FireTimer is assigned a value of 0.0f and the FireRate is assigned 0.3f.

All bullets are drawn and given the same position when I call this method. Can anybody tell me what needs to be done to get them to be positioned at the position in 0.3sec intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking the firetimer when the key is down, then you iterate over the entire array and fire each bullet. You will want a variable to store the current index in the clip, then increment it each time a bullet is fired.

```
int clipIndex = 0;

...


FireTimer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && clipIndex < bullets.Count() FireTimer > FireRate)
{
    if (bullets[clipIndex].IsAlive == false)
    {
        bullets[i].IsAlive = true;
        bullets[i].position = position;
        FireTimer = 0f;
    }
    clipIndex++;
 }
```

You could then reload by changing the index back to 0; Another thing to be aware of, if the bullet's flag IsAlive is true, then this miss fire for a single frame. If you wanted to just find the next alive bullet you could do a while statement:

```
while (bullets[clipIndex].IsAlive && clipIndex < bullets.Count())
    clipIndex++;

if (clipIndex < bullets.Count())
    ...
```

The if statement changes because you know that clipIndex will be the index of a bullet that isn't alive, but you do want to make sure there IS a bullet.